# How to import BrowserAnimationModule when use Lazy Loading angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

How to use BrowserAnimationModule when Lazy Loading angular. But I use loadchildren routing angular, must important CommonModule but need use component which dependencies BrowserAnimationModule.

Comment: Add BrowserAnimationModule to main module and solved.

Comment: Replacing BrowserModule with BrowserAnimationModule, did the job for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add BrowserAnimationModule to main module and solved.